# Traverse a directory tree and output a list of all files

Tags: code-golf, tree-traversal, file-system

Write the shortest code that traverses a directory tree and outputs a flat list of all files.

- It should traverse the whole directory tree
- The order in which it enters sub-directories doesn't matter
- The directories should not be output
- The output should be a plain list — the definition is flexible, but it shouldn't contain irrelevant data
- You are free to use any programming technique

Comment: Two questions. 1: what about files in subdirectories? 2: If I do it in bash, can I just use `ls` (or, recursively, `ls -R`)?

Answer (score 8):

## find 14 characters (12 on GNU)

```
find . -type f
```

Run this in the directory you want to list. Add `-printf '%f\n'` to only print names without the path.

Non-portable: `find -type f`.

Comment: GNU `find` seems to let you omit the `. ` for a 2 char saving.  Doesn't seem to work with the BSD `find` in OSX though.

Comment: '-printf' is a GNU find extension. GNU find has assimilated parts of the functionality of 'stat' and 'xargs'. These extensions are not available allwhere in tne unix world (as kindly being warned by the name GNU (GNU is not Unix!)).

Comment: I sometimes wonder if non-GNU tools have any functionality at all. Everything that I use seems to be GNU-specific :)

Answer (score 6):

## Pure Bash, 7

"ls -R" and "find" are the obvious, already mentioned common shell utilities.  For completeness, we also have this pure bash option (no utility programs):

```
echo **
```

This requires the "globstar" shell option to be set with `shopt -s globstar`.

## Note:

This works only for Bash 4.0 and greater.

Answer (score 4):

## Python

[Aleksi Torhamo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24195/5133) is the correct and idiomatic one. My answer is just an exercise of what if there was no [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

I was inspired by an elegant [recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1684795/596361) for Emacs Lisp that does the same.

```
from os import *
from os.path import *
def walk(path):
    return [basename(f) for f in listdir2(path) if not isdir(f)] +\
        sum([walk(f) for f in listdir2(path) if isdir(f)], [])
```

`listdir2` here is a non-existent function that returns absolute paths of files in a directory. Unfortunately, `listdir` [doesn't return absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15452633/596361), therefore i had to manually enter and exit directories with `chdir`, so my result wasn't a slick one-liner.

```
from os import *
from os.path import *
def walk(path, old_path):
    chdir(path)
    result = [f for f in listdir(path) if not isdir(f)] +\
        sum([walk(join(path, f), getcwd()) for f in listdir(path) if isdir(f)], [])
    chdir(old_path)
    return result
```

To understand it you must read about [`os.chdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir), [`os.getcwd`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd), [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir), [`os.path.isdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir), [`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename), [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum). The function creates a list of files and recursively repeats this for sub-directories. The list of sub-directories is summed up and appended to the list of original files.

We iterate thru list 2 times, this is inefficient. Better to partition the list into files and directories in one go. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4579086/596361) proposes a smart use of `reduce`:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x[not p(y)].append(y) or x, l, ([], []))
```

## Attempt #1 (<s>179</s> 171)

```
from os import*
def w(p,o):chdir(p);r=[f for f in listdir(p)if not path.isdir(f)]+sum([w(path.join(p,f),getcwd())for f in listdir(p)if path.isdir(f)],[]);chdir(o);return r
```

## Attempt #2 (<s>190</s> 178)

```
from os import *
def u(p,o):chdir(p);a,b=reduce(lambda x,y:x[path.isdir(y)].append(y)or x,listdir(p),([],[]));r=a+sum((u(path.join(p,c),getcwd())for c in b),[]);chdir(o);return r
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! In [tag:code-golf] it's OK to do the inefficient approach if it saves you bytes. :)

Comment: I agree with @JonathanVanMatre here, a) Welcome, and b) code golf doesn't care so long as you bring it down to as few bytes as possible... The 179 approach is pretty cool... Very nice SindiKat!

Comment: Small tip for golfing in python that could save you a byte or two: You'd be surprised at some places that whitespace isn't required. For example, `from os import*` is valid.

Comment: @sindikat: nice. when I wrote that comment, I actually thought changing the `walk(f)` to `walk(path+'/'+f)` would've been enough, I didn't realize the `isdir()` calls used `f` too. I think it might still be shorter to do the `path+'/'+f` thing in all three places instead of passing `old_dir` and doing two `chdir()`s, though. (Although `os.path.join` is definitely the *correct* way to do it :) Changing the strategy a bit and doing the `isdir()` straight to the `path` argument would probably be even shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## DOS (11 characters)

`dir/s/b/a-d`

I love the simplicity, `/s` allows `dir` to traverse through all subfolders, while `/b` suppresses the header and directory information. `/a-d` suppresses outputting of directories. A quick check to see if the additional space was required, and I was happy enough to submit this...

Comment: +1. Though this breaks the third rule `The directories should not be output`. Add `/a-d` to suppress the outputting of directories.

Comment: Or better yet `/aa` which will only show `Files ready for archiving` - which should be all files. Might not always be as accurate as `/a-d` but it saves a character.

Comment: Hold on a second... "The directories should not be output" is a bit vague... Does that mean that the header information with regards to the directory should not be output, or that the directory path cannot be output?

Big difference...

Comment: @sindikat, can you please clarify? Are directory paths allowed in my case? What's the point of listing all files in a filesystem without a point of reference? Using /a-d strips the output of this reference point? So if anything UncleMeat's edit of my code screws this up, right?

Comment: good point, I took it as 'only enumerate all files in the tree'. Using `/a-d` doesn't ruin doesn't ruin the point of reference, as each file has it's entire directory path. It just removes outputting the directories themselves.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3 - 53 characters

Two equally long ways for doing it:

```
import os;print(*sum((x[2]for x in os.walk('.')),[]))
```

and

```
import os;print(*sum(list(zip(*os.walk('.')))[2],[]))
```

These print the filenames separated by spaces on one line, I assumed that counts as a "flat list".

Answer (score 3):

## C - <strike>203</strike> 194

This example works when compiled with TCC:

```
t(char*p){DIR*d;struct dirent*e;if(d=opendir(p))while(e=readdir(d)){char*n=e->d_name,f[PATH_MAX];sprintf(f,"%s/%s",p,n);if((*n++-46|*n&(*n++-46|*n))&&!t(f))printf("%s\n",f);}return!closedir(d);}
```

This recursive function displays the path of every file present in the folder which path has been given as a parameter.

*Note:* one character had to be added to get the same result with GCC:

```
int t(char*p){DIR*d;struct dirent*e;if(d=opendir(p))while(e=readdir(d)){char f[PATH_MAX];char*n=e->d_name;sprintf(f,"%s/%s",p,n);if((*n++-46|*n&&(*n++-46|*n))&&!t(f))printf("%s\n",f);}return!closedir(d);}
```

I replaced `&` with `&&` in the condition. I guess the `&` operator has priority over `&&` in TCC syntax, while the opposite occurs with GCC.

See the full working example here: http://ideone.com/lGBtJw

## C - <strike>220</strike> 215 (full program with include)

I liked that Coaumdio used a full program to answer... so I started adapting mine, here is the result:

```
#include<dirent.h>
main(i,char**p){DIR*d=opendir(*++p);char*n,f[4096],*a=f;struct dirent*e;d||puts(*p);if(d)while(e=readdir(d))sprintf(f,"%s/%s",*p,n=e->d_name),(*n++-46|*n&&(*n++-46|*n))&&main(i,&a-1);closedir(d);}
```

Expanded version:

```
#include<dirent.h>

int main(int i,char**p){
    DIR*d=opendir(*++p);
    char f[4096],*n,*a=f;
    struct dirent*e;
    d||puts(*p);
    if(d)while(e=readdir(d))
        sprintf(f,"%s/%s",*p,n=e->d_name),
        (*n++-46|*n&&(*n++-46|*n))&&main(i,&a-1);
    closedir(d);
}
```

Usage:

```
gcc list_files.c -o list_files
./list_files /var
```

Answer (score 2):

**Bash**, 18

```
ls -R
```

**Windows CMD.**

```
dir /S
```

Compliant version

```
ls -R1|grep -v ^./
```

Comment: `ls -R` unfortunately prints the headers for each directory. It may not count as a "flat list".

Comment: As does `dir /S`, this also displays the header information...

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>216</strike> 228 chars (#include included)

The other C solution contians nice tricks, but as I like compilable complete C solutions, here is my shot:

```cpp
#include <dirent.h>
main(int _,char**v){char n[4096],*a=n,*b;DIR*d;struct dirent*e;(d=opendir(*++v))||puts(*v);while(d&&(e=readdir(d)))b=e->d_name,sprintf(n,"%s/%s",*v,b),strcmp(".",b)&&strcmp("..",b)&&main(0,&a-1);}
```

It's also a recursive traversal algorithm, and it's using the `main` function as recursive function. The main function tries to open the path contained in `argv[1]`. If it fails, it prints it, otherwise, it calls main on every sub-element (if it's different from `"."` or `".."`).

### Usage

It's a standalone, working C program:

```
$ gcc dir.c -o dir
$ ./dir /var.log   
/var/log/kern.log.1
/var/log/alternatives.log.1
/var/log/user.log.2.gz
/var/log/nvidia-installer.log
/var/log/debug.4.gz
/var/log/wtmp.1
/var/log/lastlog
/var/log/messages.2.gz
/var/log/vmware-installer
/var/log/pm-powersave.log
/var/log/syslog.4.gz
/var/log/news/news.err
/var/log/news/news.notice
/var/log/news/news.crit
/var/log/apt/history.log.3.gz
/var/log/apt/history.log.9.gz
/var/log/apt/history.log.4.gz
/var/log/apt/term.log.10.gz
/var/log/apt/history.log.10.gz
/var/log/apt/term.log.4.gz
```

### Tips

I used a few (somewhat classic) C tricks:

- replace `if(condition)statement` with `contition && statement`
- replace `if(!condition)statement` with `condition || statement`
- use the `,` operator to save `{` and `}` in the while code

Here is a readable version:

```cpp
#include <dirent.h>
main(int _,char**v) {
    char n[4096], *a=n,*b;
    DIR *d; 
    struct dirent *e; 
    (d = opendir(*++v)) || puts(*v);
    while(d && (e = readdir(d)))
        b = e->d_name,
        sprintf(n, "%s/%s", *v, b), 
        strcmp(".", b)&&strcmp("..", b)&&
            main(0, &a-1);
}
```

### Edit

I have to insert a `closedir(d);` statement at the end, because a limit is reached when too much folders are opened (wild guess: the *open files* limit) and the the program stops. This happens only for folder containing many other folders.

the code is now:

```cpp
#include <dirent.h>
main(int _,char**v){char n[4096],*a=n,*b;DIR*d;struct dirent*e;(d=opendir(*++v))||puts(*v);while(d&&(e=readdir(d)))b=e->d_name,sprintf(n,"%s/%s",*v,b),strcmp(".",b)&&strcmp("..",b)&&main(0,&a-1);closedir(d);}
```

Comment: Without `closedir(d)`, this will abruptely stop if you traverse a big directory (for instance, `/`)... I also tried to do without the `closedir`, but had to retract for this reason.

Comment: Oh c**p, you're absolutely right! I thought not using closedir was only dirty. Well that's 12 more chars then.

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy 58

```
new File("/").eachFileRecurse(){if(it.isFile())println it}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### CMD - 32 Bytes

Another CMD / DOS method -

```
for /r %a in (*)do @echo %~dpnxa
```

The `/r` switch recursively looks through a directory (defaulting to current directory), while `%~dpnxa` outputs `%a`, the current directory or file in the loop, to the following output format -

`d` - drive
`p` - path
`n` - name
`x` - extension

Because `x` is specified it will only output files, ignoring directories.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy 45

Now even shorter:

```java
new File(".").traverse{if(it.file)println it}
```

Uses one of the [traverse() methods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#traverse(java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) available since Groovy 1.7.1.

## Groovy 46 ;-)

Another nice solution, if you don't count the required `import` statement, is this one:

```java
import groovy.io.FileType.*
new File(".").traverse type:FILES,{println it}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 18 characters

```
puts Dir['./**/*']
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 11, 52 bytes

```
Files.list(Path.of("")).forEach(System.out::println)
```

## Java, 87 bytes

```
void t(File f){if(f.isFile())System.out.println(f);else for(File c:f.listFiles())t(c);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 78 bytes

```
DIM F$[0],D$[0]FILES"//",D$@L
FILES POP(D$),F$WHILE LEN(F$)?POP(F$)WEND
GOTO@L
```

Displays a `*` or   before each filename, depending on whether it's a text file (is this allowed?)